# String storage in C

Tags: c

I was trying to help a student friend understand his C lesson (talking pointers, adresses, ...) and he asked me why in this picture 'e' has memory adress 5004 why did we increase by 4 ? (what does 4 represent ?)
I know string storage can depend on the physical machine arch but I'd like some simple explanation since I'm myslef not that strong in C.

the pic is from http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syl-ARM/2-C-adv-data/string.html
[image]

Comment: The example would appear to be wrong. Just above, it says "A string is stored in memory using **consecutive memory cells**". In C you'd get that 4 if it were an array of 32-bit values.

Comment: @SaucyGoat I don't know if it's 32 bit arch, everything is in the article. I can't give any info other than what is mentionned

Comment: thanks for the explanation @WeatherVane

Comment: In this [link](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syl-ARM/4-intro/memory1.html), it seems to imply , at the end, that the course considers a 32 bit architecture.

Comment: Underneath it says "So 'H' is nothing more than a small (1 byte) integer". But they show 4-byte locations. This is also confusing because in C `'H'` is not a `char` type but an `int` type.

Comment: This pic is certainly wrong, but **could** be right on some unicorn implementation where the address goes up by 4 on each byte.  On such a machine with `char *s = "Hello";`, `&s[1] - &s[0]` would still be 1 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each character in c takes 1 byte. I am not sure that this diagram is correct since memory is typically byte addressable so the ‘e’ should be one byte away from the ‘h’.

Typically, memory addresses are incremented by 4 because that is how many bytes are used to store an integer which is one of the more common data types in c.

Answer (score 2):

That picture seems to be **wrong**, but I'll try to take something learnable out of it.

Most modern systems are [byte addressable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing) rather than [word addressable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-addressable). This means that each individual byte, no matter the data type, will be referenced by an address.

Now in this case they mention a contiguous array of chars, which means that the array values and corresponding addresses would be laid out as follows:

```
'h' -> 5000
'e' -> 5001
'l' -> 5002
'l' -> 5003
'o' -> 5004
'\0' -> 5005
```

However, take this example: `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};`. In this case (64-bit machine), the starting addresses for each value of the array would "hop" in values of 4. That is because, since each `int` is 4 bytes long, each of them will need 4 addresses. Here are the addresses in that hypothetical scenario:

```
1 -> 5000
2 -> 5004
3 -> 5008
4 -> 500C
```